# Webpack bundling simple JS files

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I realize this might prove a total misunderstanding of what *Webpack* is for but I've not been able to find a straight answer anywhere.

Basically I have two files:

**hello.js**

```
function hello() {
    console.log('Hello, world!');
}
```

**entry.js**

```
require('./hello.js');

hello(); // should log 'Hello, world!'
```

I wanted to pack them into a single file for faster loading using *Webpack*. My condition was that I should not have to modify **hello.js** in any way (let's say it is a big, obfuscated library that I don't have the right to modify).

I expected that running

```
webpack entry.js result.js
```

will give me a usable bundle in `result.js` but instead `result.js` gives me this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want? Just simply bundle scripts together to make them available in the global namespace without having to add anything to them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File hello.js is not exporting anything, you have to export hello function from hello.js file like this,

```
module.exports = function () {
  console.log('Hello, world!');
}
```

and then in your entry file.

```
var hello = require('./hello.js');
hello();
```

Comment: So there is no way to do this without modifying `hello.js` ?

Comment: You will have to export the methods/objects/etc.  to expose it globally which you can use in another file, otherwise it will be private to that module.

Comment: Its for your benefit webpack is not doing that, one day you'll thank webpack for this awesome feature and many more.